# How do I fill a vertex' shape with an image in processing?

Tags: processing

When I use my code it says: No uv text coordinates supplied with vertex() call.
This is the code I use:

```java
PImage img;

void setup() {
size(720, 360, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  beginShape();
  img = loadImage("image.png");
  texture(img);
  vertex(50, 20);
  vertex(105, 20);
  vertex(105, 75);
  vertex(50, 75);
  endShape();
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole error output.

Comment: @MatthieuSjollema You are passing the x,y coordinates but not the u,v texture coordinates to the `vertex()` call indeed. Checkout [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451575/processing-using-texture-inside-the-audio-waveform/44458640#44458640) for more explanations on uv tex. coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Like your error and George's comment say, to use a texture you need to pass in 4 parameters to the `vertex()` function instead of 2 parameters.

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/texture_.html):

```java
size(100, 100, P3D);
noStroke();
PImage img = loadImage("laDefense.jpg");
beginShape();
texture(img);
vertex(10, 20, 0, 0);
vertex(80, 5, 100, 0);
vertex(95, 90, 100, 100);
vertex(40, 95, 0, 100);
endShape();
```

[image: texture]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/images/texture_.png))</sub>

Also note that you should not be loading your image inside the `draw()` function, because that causes you to load the same image 60 times per second. You should load it once from the `setup()` function.